# Android Webview - XML?

Tags: android

Is there a way to define a webview in the layout xml rather than in the code.

And if so how? Or is it recommended that it's coded in to an activity?

Answer (score 10):

Yes as above use the WebView tag:

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50dip"/>
```

A sample application can be found here:
http://www.androiddom.com/2011/04/creating-android-calculator-tutorial.html

The author creates a calculator that uses the WebView which is specified in the main.xml layout.

Comment: what of webview androidx xml?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the `<WebView />` tag to do this in the xml layout.

Comment: Great, can I set the url by the xml too?

Comment: I do not believe you can. Here is another post with a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219794/how-to-set-url-on-webview-from-a-xml-layout-file-on-android

Answer (score 0):

and in your code type this :

```
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
wv.loadUrl("your url here");
```

Comment: What is the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method used for?